# Rename button on Filechooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

How to rename button in Filechooser, from Open to Save as for example

```
     saveAsButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt")) {
                fw.write(textPane1.getText().toString());
                fw.flush();
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `JFileChooser#showSaveDialog` instead of `JFileChooser#showOpenDialog`

I would recommend having a look at [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) and [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) for more details

Of course, if you want more control over the button text, then you should have a look at [`JFileChooser#setApproveButtonText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setApproveButtonText-java.lang.String-) and it's associated methods

> approveButtonText is reset to defaul, if showOpenDialog or showSaveDialog is called

You know, it's funny, I've been using this approach for years and it seems to have been working.

I dug into the `JFileChooser` code and found that `showOpen/SaveDialog` calls this...

```
public void setDialogType(int dialogType) {
    if(this.dialogType == dialogType) {
        return;
    }
    checkDialogType(dialogType);
    int oldValue = this.dialogType;
    this.dialogType = dialogType;
    if(dialogType == OPEN_DIALOG || dialogType == SAVE_DIALOG) {
        setApproveButtonText(null);
    }
    firePropertyChange(DIALOG_TYPE_CHANGED_PROPERTY, oldValue, dialogType);
}
```

This "should" be reseting the approve button text, but for some reason, in my testing, `showOpenDialog` works, lets talk weird...

```
public class CustomFileChooser extends JFileChooser {

    @Override
    public void setDialogType(int dialogType) {
        String currentApproveText = getApproveButtonText();
        super.setDialogType(dialogType);
        setApproveButtonText(currentApproveText);
    }

}
```

So, what's the solution?  Well, you could use `showDialog` instead, which sets it up as a `CUSTOM_DIALOG`, but I'm to lazy for that :P

Another solution might be to simply override `setDialogType` and reapply the `approveButtonText`, something like...

```
public class CustomFileChooser extends JFileChooser {

    @Override
    public void setDialogType(int dialogType) {
        String currentApproveText = getApproveButtonText();
        super.setDialogType(dialogType);
        setApproveButtonText(currentApproveText);
    }

}
```

Comment: approveButtonText is reset to defaul, if showOpenDialog or showSaveDialog is called

Comment: @emi-le You know what's funny, the code says it shouldn't work for `openDialog`, but it does